# How to get image size from SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage to get image from url. I want to get the size of remote image in order to do some layout calculation. Since I only know the url of the image, how can I get it from SDWebImage object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one, Its may be work for you

```
-(UIImage *)downloadImageAsync:(NSString *)imageKey
 {
     NSLog(@"image key : %@",imageKey);
      __block UIImage *returnedImage;
     SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
     [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageKey] options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize){
    NSLog(@"received size %d expected size %lld", receivedSize, expectedSize);

    }completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType,BOOL finished){
      if(image && finished) {
        returnedImage = image;
      }
   }];

   if(returnedImage == nil) {
      NSLog(@"Returned Image Nil");
   }
    return returnedImage;
}
```

Comment: This will always return `nil` by the way.

Comment: no, try it. Its working for me. please check it any think wrong

Comment: You can try this one also ---->  SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self options:0 success:^(UIImage *image) 
{
    cell.profilePicture.image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width, cell.profilePicture.frame.size.height) image:image];
} failure:nil];

Comment: did you got your solution?